# What needs to be updated to make the JUnit5 test successful?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I have created this Java project for my Computer Science course at SNHU and am getting tripped up and confused as to why I am getting these errors when running a JUnit5 test on the code. The errors that I am receiving when running the JUnit5 test are:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: First name was not null. == > expected: not < null > 
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java: 39)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java: 134)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.failNull(AssertNotNull.java: 47)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java: 36)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java: 308)
    at module3.ContactTest.testContactFirstNameNotNull(ContactTest.java: 76)
    at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java: 64)
    at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java: 43)
    at java.base / java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java: 725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java: 60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java: 131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java: 149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java: 140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java: 84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java: 115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java: 105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java: 106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java: 64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java: 45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java: 37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java: 104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java: 98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java: 214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java: 73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java: 210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java: 135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java: 66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java: 151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java: 73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java: 141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java: 137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java: 139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java: 73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java: 138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java: 95)
    at java.base / java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java: 1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java: 41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java: 155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java: 73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java: 141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java: 137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java: 139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java: 73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java: 138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java: 95)
    at java.base / java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java: 1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java: 41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java: 155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java: 73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java: 141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java: 137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java: 139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java: 73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java: 138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java: 95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java: 35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java: 57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java: 54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java: 107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java: 88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java: 54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java: 67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java: 52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java: 114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java: 95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java: 91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java: 60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java: 98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java: 40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java: 529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java: 756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java: 452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java: 210)
```

I am running this project in Eclipse and it is up to date on software. Below are the instructions as well as the code for this assignment.

**Instructions:**

> Overview
>
> As you have learned in Modules One and Two, various types of software
> testing can be employed for a given situation. For this assignment,
> you will be creating unit tests using code to uncover errors for a
> mobile application. You will develop the contact service and contact
> object.
>
> Prompt
>
> For Project One, which is due in Module Six, you are asked to develop
> a mobile application for a customer. The customer will provide you
> with the requirements. Your job is to code the application and provide
> unit tests to verify that the application meets the customer’s
> requirements. For this milestone, you will focus on delivering the
> contact services. The purpose of these services is to add, update, and
> delete contact objects within the application.
>
> The contact service uses in-memory data structures to support storing
> contacts (no database required). In addition, there is no user
> interface for this milestone. You will verify the contact service
> through JUnit tests. The contact service contains a contact object
> along with the contact service. The requirements are outlined below.
>
> Contact Class Requirements
>
> - The contact object shall have a required unique contact ID string that cannot be longer than 10 characters. The contact ID shall not be
>   null and shall not be updatable.
> - The contact object shall have a required firstName String field that cannot be longer than 10 characters. The firstName field shall
>   not be null.
> - The contact object shall have a required lastName String field that cannot be longer than 10 characters. The lastName field shall not be
>   null.
> - The contact object shall have a required phone String field that must be exactly 10 digits. The phone field shall not be null.
> - The contact object shall have a required address field that must be no longer than 30 characters. The address field shall not be null.
>
> Contact Service Requirements
>
> - The contact service shall be able to add contacts with a unique ID.
> - The contact service shall be able to delete contacts per contact ID.
> - The contact service shall be able to delete contacts per contact ID.
> - The contact service shall be able to update contact fields per contact ID. The following fields are updatable:
> - firstName
> - lastName
> - Number
> - Address

**Contact.java**

```java
//Description: This is the contact class. It creates and stores contact information.

package module3;

public class Contact {

    String contactID;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String phoneNumber;
    String address;
  
    public Contact(String contactID, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber) {
        super();
        this.contactID = contactID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.address = address;
    }
  
    public String getContactID() {
        return contactID;
    }

    public void setContactID(String contactID) {
        this.contactID = contactID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [contactID=" + contactID + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
               + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }
  
}
```

**ContactService.java:**

```java
//Description: This is the contact service. It maintains a list of contacts and has capabilities
//for adding and deleting contacts, as well as updating first name, last name, phone number, and address.

package module3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactService {
    //will contain our list of contacts

    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;

    public ContactService() {
        //beginning call for the array list
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //need to have an add contact, remove contact and update contact feature
    //set add contact to have all values
    public boolean addContact(Contact contact) {
        boolean contactAlready = false;
        //run through all the contacts in the list made
        for (Contact contactList : contacts) {
            //test to see if already a contact
            //if so make contactAlready true
            if (contactList.equals(contact)) {
                contactAlready = true;
            }
        }
        //if not a contact add it as one
        if (!contactAlready) {
            contacts.add(contact);
            //after adding is now true
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //delete needed via contactID
    public boolean deleteContact(String string) {
        //run through list of contacts
        for (Contact contactList : contacts) {
            //if equals to contactID will remove and return
            if (contactList.getContactID().equals(string)) {
                //remove and return true
                contacts.remove(contactList);
                return true;
            }
        }
        //else return false
        return false;
    }

    //update is trickiest due to needing to make sure still fits parameters
    //nothing means no change
    public boolean updateContact(String contactID, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber,
            String address) {
        //run through loop again
        for (Contact contactList : contacts) {
            //if contactID matches, run through each with making sure not "" and meets requirements
            //then return true as it did equal update.
            if (contactList.getContactID().equals(contactID)) {
                if (!firstName.equals("") && !(firstName.length() > 10)) {
                    contactList.setFirstName(firstName);
                }
                if (!lastName.equals("") && !(lastName.length() > 10)) {
                    contactList.setFirstName(lastName);
                }
                if (!phoneNumber.equals("") && (phoneNumber.length() == 10)) {
                    contactList.setFirstName(phoneNumber);
                }
                if (!address.equals("") && !(address.length() > 30)) {
                    contactList.setFirstName(address);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        //else return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ContactTest.java:**

```java
//Description: This is the unit tests for the contact class (ContactTest).

package module3;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class ContactTest {
    /*
     * The following tests exercise the Contact class.
     * The first 5 tests to make sure the field does not become longer than the constraint
     * (10 characters for first and last name, exactly 10 characters for phone number,
     * and 30 characters for the address).
     * The last 4 tests ensure that each field is not null.
     * ContactID is not tested for being not null because there isn't a way to create
     * a contact with a null contactID. Likewise it is not tested for being non-updateable
     * because there is no way to update it.
     */
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact ID cannot have more than 10 characters")
    void testContactIDWithMoreThanTenCharacters() {
        Contact contact = new Contact("FirstName", "LastName", "PhoneNumbr", "Address");
        if (contact.getContactID().length() > 10) {
            fail("Contact ID has more than 10 characters.");
        }
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact First Name cannot have more than 10 characters")
    void testContactFirstNameWithMoreThanTenCharacters() {
        Contact contact = new Contact("OllyOllyOxenFree", "LastName", "PhoneNumbr", "Address");
        if (contact.getFirstName().length() > 10) {
            fail("First Name has more than 10 characters.");
        }
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact Last Name cannot have more than 10 characters")
    void testContactLastNameWithMoreThanTenCharacters() {
        Contact contact = new Contact("FirstName", "OllyOllyOxenFree", "PhoneNumbr", "Address");
        if (contact.getLastName().length() > 10) {
            fail("Last Name has more than 10 characters.");
        }
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact phone number is exactly 10 characters")
    void testContactNumberWithMoreThanTenCharacters() {
        Contact contact = new Contact("FirstName", "LastName", "55555555555", "Address");
        if (contact.getPhoneNumber().length() != 10) {
            fail("Phone number length does not equal 10.");
        }
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact address cannot have more than 30 characters")
    void testContactAddressWithMoreThanThirtyCharacters() {
        Contact contact = new Contact("FirstName", "LastName", "PhoneNumbr", "123456789 is nine characters long"
                + "123456789 is another nine characters long");
        if (contact.getAddress().length() > 30) {
            fail("Address has more than 30 characters.");
        }
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact First Name shall not be null")
    void testContactFirstNameNotNull() {
        Contact contact = new Contact(null, null, null, null);
        assertNotNull(contact.getFirstName(), "First name was not null.");
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact Last Name shall not be null")
    void testContactLastNameNotNull() {
        Contact contact = new Contact(null, null, null, null);
        assertNotNull(contact.getLastName(), "Last name was null.");
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact Phone Number shall not be null")
    void testContactPhoneNotNull() {
        Contact contact = new Contact("FirstName", "LastName", null, "Address");
        assertNotNull(contact.getPhoneNumber(), "Phone number was null.");
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Contact Address shall not be null")
    void testContactAddressNotNull() {
        Contact contact = new Contact(null, null, null, null);
        assertNotNull(contact.getAddress(), "Address was null.");
    }
}
```

**ContactServiceTest.java:**

```java
//Description: This is the unit tests for the contact service (ContactServiceTest)

package module3;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ContactServiceTest {

    //need to test add, delete and update
    //templates
    /*
    * Contact("1413252", "Jane", "Doe", "4444444444", "Sample 24 Drive");
    Contact("1309403", "Malleus", "Draconia", "2187123404", "Valley of Thorns");
    Contact("9752319", "Vil", "Schoenheit", "9215501793", "Land of Proxynee");
    */

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        ContactService cs = new ContactService();
        Contact test1 = new Contact("1413252", "Jane", "Doe", "4444444444");
        assertEquals(true, cs.addContact(test1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDelete() {
        ContactService cs = new ContactService();

        Contact test1 = new Contact("1413252", "Jane", "Doe", "4444444444");
        Contact test2 = new Contact("1309403", "Malleus", "Draconia", "2187123404");
        Contact test3 = new Contact("9752319", "Vil", "Schoenheit", "9215501793");

        cs.addContact(test1);
        cs.addContact(test2);
        cs.addContact(test3);

        assertEquals(true, cs.deleteContact("1309403"));
        assertEquals(false, cs.deleteContact("1309404"));
        assertEquals(false, cs.deleteContact("1309403"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        ContactService cs = new ContactService();

        Contact test1 = new Contact("1413252", "Jane", "Doe", "4444444444");
        Contact test2 = new Contact("1309403", "Malleus", "Draconia", "2187123404");
        Contact test3 = new Contact("9752319", "Vil", "Schoenheit", "9215501793");

        cs.addContact(test1);
        cs.addContact(test2);
        cs.addContact(test3);

        assertEquals(true, cs.updateContact("9752319", "VilFirst", "SchoenheitLast", "9215501793", "Land of Proxynee"));
        assertEquals(false, cs.updateContact("9752322", "VilFirst", "SchoenheitLast", "9215501793", "Land of Proxynee"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through you code, these were few mistakes that I could figure out due to which your tests are failing.

> TEST 1

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Contact address cannot have more than 30 characters")
void testContactAddressWithMoreThanThirtyCharacters() {
    
Contact contact = new Contact("FirstName","LastName","PhoneNumbr","123456789 is nine characters long"
+ "123456789 is another nine characters long");
System.out.println("contact address i ---------" + contact.getAddress().length());
if(contact.getAddress().length() > 30) {
fail("Address has more than 30 characters.");
}
}
```

**REASON FOR FAILING :**

When creating object contact, you have are not passing value for address as your constructor  has only these values :

```
public Contact(String contactID, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber)
```

Thus, your address value is by default null only. When you apply any method call on a null object`(contact.getAddress().length())` , it gives Null Pointer Exception.

> TEST 2

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Contact phone number is exactly 10 characters")
void testContactNumberWithMoreThanTenCharacters() {
Contact contact = new Contact("FirstName", "LastName", "5555555555","Address");

if(contact.getPhoneNumber().length() != 10) {
fail("Phone number length does not equal 10.");
}
}
```

**REASON FOR FAILING :**

You are passing the string address instead of your phone number :
You have to rectify your test to pass

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Contact phone number is exactly 10 characters")
void testContactNumberWithMoreThanTenCharacters() {
Contact contact = new Contact("FirstName", "LastName", "Address","5555555555");
System.out.println("contact digits  i ---------" + contact.getPhoneNumber().length() );
if(contact.getPhoneNumber().length() != 10) {
fail("Phone number length does not equal 10.");
}
}
```

Also , if instead of creating a new object before running every test, you should actually use **@Before annotation** to create initialization condition before running each test.

**RECTIFICATION**:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Contact address cannot have more than 30 characters")
void testContactAddressWithMoreThanThirtyCharacters() {
    
Contact c1 = new Contact("FirstName","LastName","value is","PhoneNumbr","address is longer than 30 characters ");
System.out.println("contact address i ---------" + c1.getAddress().length());
System.out.println("contact address i ---------" + c1.getAddress());
System.out.println(c1);
assertTrue(c1.getAddress().length() > 30);
}
```

After doing these rectifications, all the tests pass
[image]

Comment: How did you get the "Contact address cannot have more than 30 characters" to pass without an error?

Comment: define a constructor in your contact class which initializes address also

Comment: @MathewDawson I have edited the answer with rectification for test 2 which is failing. Please have a look

Comment: @MathewDawson the print statement were part of debugging . you can remove them